# Entity Framework Core RC2 dotnet ef not valid application for this OS platform

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, .net-core-rc2

I have a ASP.Net Core project where I have been trying to scaffold an existing database to create a dbcontext. This is the project.json file:

```
{
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc2-final",
        "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc2-final"
      },

      "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
          "imports": [
            "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50",
            "portable-net45+win8"
          ]
        },
        "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": {
          "version": "1.0.0-preview1-final",
          "imports": "portable-net45+win8+dnxcore50"
        }
      },

      "frameworks": {
        "net452": { }
      },

      "buildOptions": {
        "emitEntryPoint": true,
        "preserveCompilationContext": true
      },

      "publishOptions": {
        "include": [
          "wwwroot",
          "Views",
          "appsettings.json",
          "web.config"
        ]
      },

      "scripts": {
        "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
      }
    }
```

Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools is "preview1 final", but I don't see any newer version, like rc2, that I could use... I had installed various different dependencies before getting to the current state, but I had executed dotnet tool to rebuild the whole project and even used the mysterious --infer-runtimes option mentioned in some answers. Still no luck.

I have PowerShell 5.0 on the machine:

```
PS C:\projectfolder> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10586  117
```

When running dotnet ef command in PowerShell, when in the project's folder, I am getting the following **error** (I replaced project name and path with "projectfolder" here). The same happens if I use the "scaffold" ef command, so here is just the simplest form of the command line to get the error:

```
PS C:\projectfolder> dotnet --verbose ef --help    
[...]
    Running C:\projectfolder\bin\Debug\net452\win7-x86\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Cli.exe --framework net452 --configuration Debug --verbose --help --dispatcher-version 1.0.0-preview1-20901
    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
       at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
       at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute()
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DispatchCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Create>b__0()
       at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
       at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

dotnet --info returns:

```
.NET Command Line Tools (1.0.0-preview1-002702)

Product Information:
 Version:     1.0.0-preview1-002702
 Commit Sha:  6cde21225e

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  6.1.7601
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win7-x86
```

The system is win7 32bit. The .Net frameworks installed on this system are:

- Core 1.0.0 RC2 - SDK Preview 1 (x86)
- Core 1.0.0 RC2 - VS 2015 Tooling
  Preview 1
- 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2, 4.6, 4.6.1

**Update**: I have also checked (again) whether it works from the VS Package Manager's command line, but (as expected I guess) it fails with the same error message:

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext -Connection 'Server=name;Database=testdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=pass' -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Verbose
Working directory: C:\projectfolder
Executing command: dotnet ef --configuration Debug --build-base-path .\bin\ dbcontext scaffold 'Server=name;Database=testdb;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=user;Password=pass' Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer --verbose
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.    at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
    at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Utils.Command.Execute() 
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DispatchCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Create>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.CommandLineUtils.CommandLineApplication.Execute(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Program.Main(String[] args)
 The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS platform.
```

**Update**: I have added "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" to project dependencies, but no difference. (I guess that assembly was already present, as a dependency of the others...)

**What am I doing wrong?*** Help... Is there anything else I should be installing/checking?

Comment: I wonder if adding "platform": "x86" in buildOptions would help. Take a look at this thread: https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3091

Comment: Thank you, Pawel. It has not helped though. I have added the x86 platform to build options. No difference to the output of the scaffolding tool...